# Learning the task execution steps for a target goal

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to model a network which can take :-

Input - A Target Goal (e.g. Go To Cinema Hall)

Output - A sequence of steps (e.g. Go To Bus Stop -> Onboard A Bus -> Drop at Location X -> Walk 100 meters.

My training data is a similar kind of Objective - Task Sequence Mappings.

Can anyone please suggest a suitable approach using DL4J to address this problem and model suitable solutions?

Comment: I'd say it's more a graph-oriented problem than a machine learning one, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

> Input - A Target Goal (e.g. Go To Cinema Hall)
>
> Output - A sequence of steps (e.g. Go To Bus Stop -> Onboard A Bus -> Drop at Location X -> Walk 100 meters.

I assume that there's no other information available to the model, such as geographical information about the possible locations (i.e. the training data is made only of examples objective + sequence). As far as I can tell this implies that there's no way to use similarity between two objectives, since there's no way to know if similar places are in the same area.

Under this definition, the objective is a single categorical variable. So there's just nothing to learn except mapping an objective with its corresponding sequence, no need for ML at all: just store the list which maps any objective in the training data to its corresponding sequence in a map (dictionary).

Comment: Hi Erwan, I understand what you say. However, my training data is going to be comprised of many of tasks where there would tasks which are reused. For e.g.

Example 2.
Input - A Target Goal (e.g. Go To School at Location Y)
Output - A sequence of steps (e.g. Go To Bus Stop -> Onboard A Bus -> Drop at Location Y.

Example2.

Comment: @AmarBanerjee do you mean that if the model has seen during training that "going to X" requires steps "bus stop -> bus -> drop at X" it should apply the same sequence replacing X with Y for any goal "going to Y"? Intuitively that seems wrong, because there's no reason to assume that the same steps are involved. For example maybe the school is just 50m from home and there's no need to take a bus.

Comment: Yes @Erwan. This was one example. It's like, if I train the machine for different ojectives like :- Go to School, Go to Office ... etc... then the machine should predict what steps need to taken to Maybe "Go to Mall". The machine may learn the generic notion of "Go To X" and then apply the learning to multiple instances.

And yes, there should not be any reason to assume that the same steps are involved. The training steps could vary depending on what the goal is. Goals could be as generic like

Comment: "Cook a turkey", and the machine should be able to learn the notion of "Cooking" from previous data and predict a very high level step plan like "Marinate -> Light Burner -> Add oil -> Add spices -> Remove after 20 mins". The notion of the abstract steps to cook should be learnt from the training data. I am not looking for concrete steps, but steps at a higher level. 
I hope I explained, what's the idea.
Thanks again.

Comment: So you would like the system to decompose the parts of the goal and assemble the corresponding steps together? It's quite difficult to understand the problem from just a couple of toy examples, actually it looks like the problem is under-specified. In all the examples you give there is one main action which directly implies most (all?) of the steps, for instance "go" or "cook", but the object of the goal is not really important for the sequence. Is that what you need? If yes it means you can treat the sequence itself as a categorical variable, so it's like a regular classification problem.

Comment: Thanks Erwan. I see what you are pointing out. Yes, the terms "Go" and "Cook" will be a part of the training data and the object of the goal is all abstract. And yes, I want the system to decompose all the steps in the goals and then assemble them together. I am still formulating the problem and hence even I am not very clear with the exact formulation.
I see a Training data structure like this to be usefule:-
[Objective String] -> [Array of String in a Sequence]. Please suggest if this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that it's going to be difficult to make the model learn (1) which part of the objective input relates to which step(s) of the sequence output and (2) even more difficult to make it correctly order different steps of the output sequence. Potentially you could consider this a sequence to sequence problem (like machine translation), but I'm not very optimistic this can work. I think I would rather decompose the problem: first step classification for the different kinds of action (e.g. "go to"), second step adapt the generic output sequence for this action to the object of this ...

Comment: ...  particular goal (e.g. "library").

Comment: Thanks a lot, Erwan. Your inputs have been very valuable to understand how to approach this problem. I understand that you are suggesting to see this as a step by step learning 1) Learn the higher level Goal 2) Learn the sequential task.. and so on. I'll see if I could try out this in an experiment, and would keep you posted. 

Cheers,